# How to make python console to echo the lines in emacs python-mode?

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

When I send a line to python console in emacs by the `py-execute-line`
function, the only thing I can observe in the console is an extra prompt:

[image]

I understand some people prefer it this way, but for me this is strange, is there a way to customize?
BTW, the prompt also looks weird, normally isn't it '>>>'?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't look like that, assume some third party stuff interferred.

Please start from emacs -Q and load a recent python-mode.el

https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+download

In case trouble persists, please file a bug report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: How do you load python-mode after `emacs-Q`?